# Change internal search path Drupal 6

Tags: drupal

Is it possible to change the search path when performing internal search in Drupal 6 from something like search/node/keyword into search/?key=keyword ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change this (in D6 at least). You can use "/search/?keys=keywords" (notice that **keys is plural** !).

Comment: Thanks, but where can I configure this path? Should I use some specific module? I've tried with the pathauto module, but (correct me if I'm wrong, since I'm new to drupal), I didn't manage to change it.